# How to fix CSS background position

Tags: css, background, position, fixed

I am building this site using fixed position for the background. The problem is
all elements seem to scroll except for the background.
Link for the site
http://automarketca.com/divasangola/index.php

Any help is very appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want the background also to scroll?

Comment: change position to absolute its fixed . it will scroll with body.

Comment: Hi Gurminder,  yes I would like the Background to move with the content what is Happening now is all content including navigation bar are moving on top of the background if you noticed from the posted link they even overlapping the logo I put on top. Any solution cause I tried changing position to absolute and it messed up the other elements on the page, Do you think positioning of other elements are wrong too?

Comment: Thanks you all for your answers. Absolute position Worked!

Comment: However the Background is now cut short, I am left with white space at the bottom of the screen, anyone knows the answer? Background image size i am using is 2500 x 1300 Pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the css for the scrolling try changing that of image

```
z-index: -999;
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 1024px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

Change fixed to absolute

Answer (score 0):

Try this css,

```
background-attachment:scroll;
```

this will make the bg scroll with the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
#full-screen-background-image {
    /*Existing Code */
    position: absolute;
}
```

This will stop it scrolling. You should also have a `z-index` on there for good measure.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `position: absolute;`

The rest of the properties and values will remain the same.